# ArcGIS Server - statistics report is empty

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, statistics, reports

Services on our DEV server are slow and I would like to figure out why using the statistics reports in ArcGIS Server Manager. But the reports I see are empty, unlike those in our TEST, ACC and PROD environments (see picture below). I have checked the ArcGIS Server Administrator Directory and all settings for usage reports are identical in all environments (see second picture below). Any idea why?

We use ArcGIS for Server 10.3.1 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

I've also asked this question on [GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/196344-arcgis-server-statistics-report-is-empty).
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug on a similar behavior by chrome. Do you see the same problem in other browsers like IE and Firefox? This [geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/187471-arcgis-server-manager-statistics-page-checkbox-error-chrome-54-55) post could be the same issue.

Comment: I use Firefox and the behaviour is the same in IE (Chrome is installed). I've tried from the server, where Chrome is not installed, same problem. Apparently the is a broader issue with the install because I can't make changes to the AG Server Administrator Directory. This is strange because everything's fine with the other environment's AG servers, and all setups should be the same.